# Version my code when published in to production or testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public class AV
{
    System.Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;

    public string currentVersion()
    {
        string VersionLabel = "Version: " + version.Major + "." + version.Minor + " " + BuildDate().ToShortDateString();
        return VersionLabel;
    }

    public DateTime BuildDate()
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("8/1/2017");
            System.Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            date = date.AddDays(version.Build);
            date = date.AddSeconds(version.Revision * 2);
            if (TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(System.DateTime.Now, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(System.DateTime.Now.Year)))
            {
                date = date.AddHours(1);
            }
            return date;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this model class in HTML and calling current version

Right now its just displaying just date how many times I publish. Its not getting the build date. Should I need to able to enable something in visual studio or need to add something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get the current build date:

```
var version = typeof(MyApplicationName.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version;
var buildDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add(new TimeSpan( TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * version.Build + TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond *2 * version.Revision));
```

This code works in my mvc app. I hope it provides some help to you. Note MyApplicationName in above code is the name of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure you set the "AssemblyVersion" to "majorversion dot minorversion dot star" in
AssemblyInfo.vb or .cs
e.g.

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>

Otherwise version.Build and version.Revision will be set by it.